# Software KVM for Ubuntu and Windows 10

Tags: windows

I have two PCs running Windows, and right now I use *Mouse Without Borders* to work with both of them.  I want to put Ubuntu on one of the PCs and still be able to use one keyboard and mouse to control them. The only option that I have found is *Synergy* but I am looking for one that's free. Does anyone have experience with this or have information for me that I can use? The others that I have found are Windows- and Mac-compatible, but not Linux.

Comment: Your best bet is probably a [KVM Switch](http://www.amazon.com/b?node=13983771).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked into this but it was not what I wanted.